# Where is System.Windows.Controls in .net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: .net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx

Says ListBoxItem is in System.Windows.Controls. Where is that namespace? The

```
using Windows.System.Controls;
```

statement fails. I'm using VS 2008, with .net 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add reference to the `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly in your project. Then the `using Windows.System.Controls;` will work.

Comment: This answer is the accepted one because it answered the question, but Jon Skeet's answer shows I was going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone else has given the answer from the point of view of the exact assembly you need to add - but my guess is that you've basically got the wrong project type. You should create a WPF or Silverlight project, and that assembly will be added for you automatically, *along with other related ones*. This is likely to be simpler than adding them each individually.

Now if you're *not* using Silverlight or WPF, you should probably think carefully before trying to use classes from WPF/Silverlight anyway - while they *may* work, it's *usually* not a good idea to mix and match presentation technologies like this. Could you give us more background on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a ListBox on a Panel in a Window in a WinForms C# project. I was trying to add things to the list, and ListBoxItem seemed the most sensible way to do it.

Comment: @Almo: No - you *don't* want to do that. Stick with Windows Forms controls if you're writing a Windows Forms application. Just add the value to to `ListBox.Items` - or using binding in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably missing a reference to `PresentationFramework.dll`. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx):

> **Assembly**:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Answer (score 1):

Also says it's in PresentationFramework assembly :)

> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Comment: Got it. Forgot to check that. :(